# np.piecewise() acting up with use of math.pow()?

Tags: python, numpy

I've been trying to get numpy.piecewise to convert a list of coefficients {a_ij} into a piecewise cubic polynomial. Whenever I run the following code,

```
import math
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0.1,9.9,100)
a = [[i] * 4 for i in range(10)]
x_i = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
condlist = [(x[i] < x)*(x<x_i[i+1]) for i in range(len(x_i)-1)]
funclist = [lambda y: sum([a[k][j] * math.pow(y - x_i[k],j) for j in range(4)]) for k in range(len(a))]
print np.piecewise(x, condlist, funclist)
```

I get the error

```
...line 730, in piecewise
y[condlist[k]] = item(vals, *args, **kw)
File "test", line 8, in <lambda>
funclist = [lambda y: sum([a[k][j] * math.pow(y - x_i[k],j) for j in range(4)]) for k in range(len(a))]
TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

The error goes away, however, if and only if I get rid of math.pow(). For some reason, having funclist pass x into math.pow() is what breaks everything.

What's going on? How can I fix this?

Comment: In general, you shouldn't mix `numpy` with Python's built-in functions, as they're not built to cooperate. You're using `np.linspace` and `np.piecewise` along with Python's `sum`, `math.pow` and `list`. I'm not sure exactly what's breaking you're code, but I'm pretty sure it's due to this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The functions in the `math` module expect numeric scalars as arguments. They don't expect NumPy arrays. The functions in `funclist` are being passed a NumPy array, `y`.
So `math.pow(y-constant, j)` is raising a TypeError:

```
In [22]: y = np.arange(5)
In [31]: math.pow(y - 1, 2)
TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

Use [`np.power`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.power.html) instead of `math.pow`:

```
funclist = [lambda y: ([a[k][j] * np.power(y - x_i[k],j) for j in range(4)]).sum()
            for k in range(len(a))]
```

Note: instead of using the Python `sum` function, you should also call the NumPy `sum` method for better performance.